# Qt 4.8 support for Mac's "elastic rubber band" scrolling

Tags: qt

Is that possible? I'm stuck with Qt 4.8 for one of our applications, for reasons beyond my control and we'd like to modernize our owner drawn QListWidgets with 'elasticity' you see today in OS X list controls (pull down to update, rubberband snap-back etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not able to upgrade to 5.0 and use the more fully fleshed out QScroller (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qscroller.html), you could try the kineticscroller project in qt labs: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/kineticscroller

You simply inherit from QKineticScroller in your class and then override the pure virtual protected methods. This will give you overshoot (the rubber band effect) and the kinetic scrolling (when you flick the scrolling continues) that you have in Mac OS X. It will take some fine tuning of the parameters to get it just right of course.

If you want to implement pull to refresh, check the `overshootDelta` parameter of the  `setContentPosition(const QPointF &pos, const QPointF &overshootDelta)` method. When this is at a sufficiently large delta (i.e. the user has pulled it down far enough), refresh your data.

**Note:** the README on the kineticscroller indicates that it landed in 4.8, but I believe there was a delay and that it didn't make it in. I can't recall exactly.